# Relationship between entries for same UniProt Id

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, pdb, uniprot

I was playing around, looking at some AlphaFold predictions for certain proteins and I realized that sometimes the sequences of aminoacid look very different for the same UniProt id. For example, 15C8 from PDB has 2 chains:

```
DIVLTQSPAIMSASLGERVTMTCTASSSVSSSNLHWYQQKPGSSPKLWIYSTSNLA
SGVPARFSGSGSGTSYSLTISSMEAEDAATYYCHQYHRSPYTFGGGTKLEIKRADA
APTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQD
SKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRN
```

and

```
EVQLQQSGAELVKPGASVKLSCTASGFNIKDTYMHWVKQKPEQGLEWIAQIDPANG
NTKYDPKFQGKATITADTSSNTAYLHLSSLTSEDSAVYYCAADPPYYGHGDYWGQG
TTLTVSSAKTTPPSVYPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSG
VHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSTWPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIV
```

At the same time, when looking at the UniProt database (the corresponding id is P01869), there's a list of multiple structures and their 3D shapes (here: https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01869). However, looking at the AlphaFold entry, I see that the amino acid sequence looks different, eg. for the case above it's:

```
AKTTPPSVYPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAV
LQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSPRPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIVPRDCGCKPCICTVP
EVSSVFIFPPKPKDVLTITLTPKVTCVVVDISKDDPEVQFSWFVDDVEVHTAQTQP
REEQFNSTFRSVSELPIMHQDWLNGKEFKCRVNSAAFPAPIEKTISKTKGRPKAPQ
VYTIPPPKEQMAKDKVSLTCMITDFFPEDITVEWQWNGQPAENYKNTQPIMNTNGS
YFVYSKLNVQKSNWEAGNTFTCSVLHEGLHNHHTEKSLSHSPGLQLDETCAEAQDG
ELDGLWTTITIFISLFLLSVCYSAAVTLFKVKWIFSSVVELKQTLVPEYKNMIGQA
P
```

My question (as someone who's just getting started with proteins) would be: what is the relationship between all these entries corresponding to the same UniProt Id?

Answer (score 1):

[PDB structure 15C8](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/15C8) corresponds to the protein product of the mouse *Igkc* gene, with the UniProt accession [P01837](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01837) as you can see in the linked page:

[image: screenshot of PDB entry 15C8]

Your [P01869](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01869) UniProt accession is for the protein product of the mouse *Ighg1* gene instead, so why would you expect these to be the same sequence? They are different proteins coded for by different genes.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I got the P01869 after looking it up in this tool: https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/ (from PDB to UniProtKB). This returns both P01837 and P01869 -- do you happen to understand why?

Comment: And in any case, my confusion regarding the amino acid sequence still holds using the correct UniProt id you mentioned, as AlphaFold has the following sequence: RADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQDSKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRNEC which is a substring of the first chain in my original post + "EC" at the end

Comment: @Andreea that's... a different question but yes, the structure predictions of AlphaFold or SwissFold or any other such collection tend to be of only _parts_ of a protein and not the entire thing. As for why you got both, that's because P01837 and P01869 are similar proteins and the specific sub-sequence whose structure has been predicted occurs in both of them.